# Accessing the Bulnes Funicular outside of Easter or August

Tags: spain, hiking

Quoting https://picosdeeuropaparquenacional.es/picos-de-europa/?lang=en,

> ACCESS TO THE CARES GORGE AND THE BULNES FUNICULAR
>
> During Easter and August, once available parking in Poncebos is full, vehicles must be parked in the Ovar parking, with 146 spaces, located 1.2 km from Poncebos. If this parking is full then parking is available in Llaneces (Arenas de Cabrales). There are bus services from both car parks to Poncebos ([www.alsa.es](http://www.alsa.es)).
>
> There are four further villages in the National Park that can be accessed by car from Poncebos: Camarmeña, Tielve, Sotres and Tresviso.

So what if you're visiting outside of Easter or August? Are the Cares Gorge and the Bulnes Funicular closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No: the quote is talking about overflow car parking in the busiest periods, and mentions alternative places in the National Park to visit if you can't get near enough to the funicular.

The opening dates and times are given by [Asturias Tourism](https://en.asturias.com/bulnes-funicular/)

> **Funicular de Bulnes: timetables and prices**
>
> - **High season** from 10:00 h. at 20:00 p.m.
>   *All summer until October 12 inclusive; on October 30 and 31 and November 1; November 11; on December 5, 6, 7 and 8.*
> - **Low season** from 10:00 h. at 12:30 h. and from 14:00 p.m. at 18:00 p.m.
>   *The rest of the year.*